# Structure Navigation Tree

Tags: structure

Is there a way to use the built-in tags available from structure or EE to list parents and their children accordingly? Essentially, something akin to the logic:

```
{exp:structure:entries channel="channel_name"}
    {if structure:child_ids_for:{entry_id} != ""}
        {!-- List all children to this parent --}
    {/if}
{/exp:structure:entries}
```

Also we need to account for third-level URLs.

Effectively, the output we're looking for is something like:

```
Parent 1
|--Child 1
|----Sub Child 1
|----Sub Child 2
|--Child 2
Parent 2
Parent 3
|--Child 1
```

And so forth. Using the `saef_select` drop-down isn't an option.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
{exp:structure:nav override_hidden_state="no" current_class="active" show_depth='1' max_depth='1' has_children_class='yes' show_overview="yes"}
```

The key is in the "show_depth" and "max_depth" parameters along with some others on the Structure [navigational tags section](http://buildwithstructure.com/tags#tag_navigation).